# Xamarin forms: How to dismiss multiple pages(Contentpage) using PopModalAsync?

Tags: xamarin.forms

My Pages flow(All pages are contentpages)

**HomePage --> GroupPage -->GroupInfoPage**

I have an exit option in GroupInfoPage. when I do exit option I need to move back to Homepage where all the groups are listed(not show the GroupPage again where all the group messages are listed).

If I call await Navigation.PopModalAsync() from GroupInfoPage I am landing to GroupPage. I need to land to homepage directly from groupinfo page.

How can I do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Set like this PopToRootAsync().Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: Exception:>System.InvalidOperationException: PopToRootAsync is not supported globally on Android, please use a NavigationPage.

Comment: While navigating from App.cs use like this  MainPage=new NavigationPage(new HomePage());

Comment: That is not possible, my first page is MainPage, where I am doing the login, can't call HomePage directly.

Comment: Ok than you can do like this MainPage=new NavigationPage(new LoginPage());

Comment: Ok so from navigating from login to main page what you are doing ,share the code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169435/discussion-between-adit-kothari-and-sreejith-sree).